# Função COUNT do PostgreSQL não funciona

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin3, pgadmin4

O problema é simples porém não consigo entender onde estou errando, preciso verificar a quantidade de resultados da seguinte sql:

```
SELECT 

f.id,sum(p.valor) as valor_fatura, f.valor_desconto as desconto, 
(f.numero || '/' || f.ano_fatura ) as numero,
(sum(p.valor) + f.valor_desconto + f.valor_acrescimo)as 
valor,f.valor_acrescimo as acrescimo, f.emissao_em,
f.vence_em, f.situacao, f.juros_acrescimo, hb.dt_hr_inclusao::date AS 
vencimento_ultimo_recalculo,
f.multa_acrescimo, f.is_gera_boleto, f.qtd_taxa_recalculo, 
f.valor_taxa_recalculo, f.is_confianca,
(sumid(p.is_baixado) = sumid(true)) as is_baixado 

FROM parcels p 
JOIN sales s ON (p.sale_id = s.id)
JOIN faturas f ON (p.fatura_cobranca_id = f.id)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT (array_agg(dt_hr_inclusao order by dt_hr_inclusao 
desc))[1] as dt_hr_inclusao,
(array_agg(cod_mov_remessa_id order by dt_hr_inclusao desc))[1] as 
cod_mov_remessa_id,
hb.fatura_id FROM historico_remessa_boleto hb GROUP BY hb.fatura_id 
) hb ON (f.id = hb.fatura_id and hb.cod_mov_remessa_id = 6)

WHERE p.is_baixado = false AND f.vence_em is not null AND is_gera_boleto 
AND consignatario_id = 6512 

GROUP BY f.id, f.numero, f.ano_fatura, f.emissao_em, f.vence_em, 
f.situacao, f.juros_acrescimo, f.multa_acrescimo, f.is_gera_boleto, 
f.valor_desconto, f.valor_acrescimo, hb.dt_hr_inclusao::date
```

O problema é que quando eu executo essa sql ela me trás 6 resultados, para saber a quantidade agora eu faria isso :

```
SELECT 
count(p.id)
FROM parcels p 
JOIN sales s ON (p.sale_id = s.id)
JOIN faturas f ON (p.fatura_cobranca_id = f.id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT (array_agg(dt_hr_inclusao order by dt_hr_inclusao 
desc))[1] as dt_hr_inclusao,
(array_agg(cod_mov_remessa_id order by dt_hr_inclusao desc))[1] as 
cod_mov_remessa_id,
hb.fatura_id FROM historico_remessa_boleto hb GROUP BY hb.fatura_id 
) hb ON (f.id = hb.fatura_id and hb.cod_mov_remessa_id = 6)

WHERE p.is_baixado = false AND f.vence_em is not null AND is_gera_boleto 
AND consignatario_id = 6512
```

Agora ela me retorna 11 resultados no count.
Não sou bom em sql meu foco é front-end então estou meio perdido de onde posso está errando, caso alguém precise de alguma informação que eu não coloquei só pedir nos comentários.

---

Quando deixo a query com o group by ela me retorna 6 linhas de resultados onde só posso ter um resultado com a quantidade total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo visto, quando você deixa com o group by retorna 6 linhas, com o resultado 6 em cada uma delas, correto ?
você pode usar o distinct para isso.

ps. Tente identar o código pra ajudar na leitura.

```
SELECT
count(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM parcels p 
JOIN sales s ON (p.sale_id = s.id)
JOIN faturas f ON (p.fatura_cobranca_id = f.id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT (array_agg(dt_hr_inclusao order by dt_hr_inclusao 
desc))[1] as dt_hr_inclusao,
(array_agg(cod_mov_remessa_id order by dt_hr_inclusao desc))[1] as 
cod_mov_remessa_id,
hb.fatura_id FROM historico_remessa_boleto hb GROUP BY hb.fatura_id 
) hb ON (f.id = hb.fatura_id and hb.cod_mov_remessa_id = 6)

WHERE p.is_baixado = false AND f.vence_em is not null AND is_gera_boleto 
AND consignatario_id = 6512 

GROUP BY f.id, f.numero, f.ano_fatura, f.emissao_em, f.vence_em, 
f.situacao, f.juros_acrescimo, f.multa_acrescimo, f.is_gera_boleto, 
f.valor_desconto, f.valor_acrescimo, hb.dt_hr_inclusao::date
```

Comment: Funcionou com uma pequena alteração, coloquei assim : count(DISTINCT f.id)

Comment: Isso! perfeito, já alterei na resposta

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Na primeira query você tem um agrupamento (`GROUP BY`). Na segunda query não. Isso altera o formato do resultado. Comparar a quantidade de registros de uma query para a outra é como comparar maçãs com laranjas.

Se você quer contar a quantide de registros da primeira query programaticamente, o ideal é fazer isso na camada de aplicação. Se você absolutamente precisa fazer isso de forma agnóstica, a maneira "suja e rápida" é encapsular a sua query e fazer assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (x) T
```

Onde `T` é um nome qualquer arbitrário e `x` é toda a query que você já colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Quando deixo com o group by ele simplesmente me trás vários resultados, onde só posso ter 1 com o total,  porém tas 6 linhas de resultado que seria 'correto' só que com o count deveria ter 1 linha com 6 de quantidade, não sei se expliquei bem.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, ao final expliquei isso.